# Microsoft Word on macOS - smooth Typing / smooth cursor

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I'm trying to figure out how to enable smooth typing (i.e. this smooth cursor animations) on macOS. On my iPad it's there and I think on Windows systems as well. What about macOS?

I've been googling for quite some time now but haven't found a definitive answer to this. It looks like that feature was once there for Word on macOS, but not anymore? Does anybody know this?

Thanks!

Comment: A quick google says it's never been on Mac. I've never seen it, so I don't miss it.

Comment: In some form, it was: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/smooth-typing-animation-on-office-2016-for-mac/d3701ae4-6ef7-4bca-b148-bc86dbdaa939

Comment: Did you read the whole thread - it came… it went. Insider build only, from what I can gather. I guess it went down like a lead balloon ;)

Comment: Yes, but it's an old thread and pretty strange thing to happen so I wanted to ask here if someone knows something definitive

Comment: It's not all that strange. Introduce a graphical 'lag' feature to people who have never seen it before, let alone it been a default setting… & they complain about it. Such is life.